# Breadth first search on trees in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, breadth-first-search

I'm writing a breadth first search algorithm in Haskell that supports pruning. It is guaranteed that the search will never encounter nodes that have been visited before, so I implemented the search as a `filter` along a stream of candidates.

I'm concerned about the efficiency of the code. Is there some slow, bad-practice code that I can try to avoid? What are some possible ways to optimize the code? Other feedback is also welcome!

```hs
bfs :: (a -> Bool) -- ^ Goal if evaluates to True
    -> (a -> Bool) -- ^ Prune if evaluates to False
    -> a  -- ^ Starting point of search
    -> (a -> [a])  -- ^ Branches at a point
    -> [a]  -- ^ Goals
bfs predicate prune a0 branch = filter predicate searchspace
    where
        -- An elegant solution
        -- searchspace = a0 : (branch =<< searchspace)
        -- However, this solution <<loop>>'s when the search is finite
        searchspace = concat $ takeWhile (not.null) epochs
        epochs = [a0] : map (\as -> [ a' | a <- as, prune a, a' <- branch a]) epochs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
bfs feasible interesting branches tree = 
  filter feasible . 
  concat . takeWhile(>[]) .
  iterate(concatMap branches . filter interesting)[tree]
```

is about as efficient as you can get if you also prune some of your finds.  Otherwise you can save some memory by pruning branches immediately after their generation as in `filter interesting . concatMap branches`